# How to avoid certain directory or files while copying from main directory?

Tags: bash, copy

Suppose I have a directory structure as the following:

```
main folder 
   sub directory 
   sub2 directory
```

I want to avoid copying a specific directory or files while copying from `main folder`.

I have looked on the internet and found a way to do it, but they used something like:

```
rsync -av --progress --exclude='logdir'
```

I am not looking to go over to size and copy. I am using a command like this:

```
cp -i -r source destination
```

I am doing it this way because of overwritten protection.

So, how to exclude certain directory or files while copying from the main directory?

Comment: Are there files in these directories? (-n, --no-clobber is commonly used to avoid overwrite)

Answer (score 1):

**One way** is to run this from within the `main folder`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "dir" ! -path . -exec cp -i -r {} /path/to/destination/ \;
```

- Change `dir` with the name of the directory to exclude.
- Change `/path/to/destination/` with the path to the destination directory.

---

**Another way** is to add a custom function like this:

```
mycp () {
        for f in "$1"*
        do
        grep -qwv  "$3" <(echo "$f") && \
        cp -i -r "$f" "$2"
        done
}
```

to your `~/.bashrc` then `source` the file or just close and reopen your terminal.

You can then use it like so:

```
mycp "/path/to/source/" "/path/to/destination/" "dir"
```

- Change `/path/to/source/` with the path to the source directory. It must end with a trailing `/`.
- Change `/path/to/destination/` with the path to the destination directory. It must end with a trailing `/`.
- Change `dir` with the name of the directory to exclude.

---

**Bash pattern matching with extended globbing way (be careful):**

Bash pattern matching with extended globbing is an option.

I only added this because [@bac0n](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328910/how-to-avoid-certain-directory-or-files-while-copying-from-main-directory/1328922#comment2265290_1328922) mentioned it in the comments. This kind of bash pattern matching requires enabling extended globbing which is not enabled by default... simple globbing is enabled by default but it wont work with this... I do not like to advise new contributors/simple users to enable and use extended globbing and especially in file operations.

Extended globbing is not by any means in its nature more dangerous than simple globbing. However, users might have scripts and bash code that they might have originally copied and pasted from the Internet and have some extended globbing patterns in them... those might behave differently when the user enables extended globbing and this might be destructive if those scripts/codes deal with file operations. An experienced user should be able to note the difference, but a beginner might not.

To use it anyway, you need to enable bash's extended globbing feature first like so:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

then use `cp` like so:

```
cp -i -r source/!(name of directory to execlude) destination/
```

For more information, please see [Bash Extended Globbing](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing)

Comment: This will not work, even if  `-name` excludes the leaf directory `cp -r` will recursive copying it anyway I believe.

Comment: @bac0n You are referring to the first way? Yes, if there are sub-directories under `dir` but `-maxdepth 1` should fix it.

Comment: why not just `cp -n -r source/!(sub directory) target/`

Comment: @bac0n That kind of bash pattern matching requires enabling extended globbing which is not enabled by default... simple globbing is enabled by default but it wont work with that...  I do not like to advise new contributors/simple users to enable and use any kind of extended globbing and especially in file operations. You need `shopt -s extglob` for that to work.

Comment: `bash_completion` enables extglob, think almost everyone has it enabled in interactive mode. (you may still need to explicitly enable it in script)

Comment: @bac0n That is not how you know if it is enabled... **It is disabled** by default and you can verify that directly by `shopt extglob` which outputs `extglob         off` on my system.