# Iterate over files withing

Tags: 20.04, bash

I have two folders, `Controls` and `Patients` within each of them there´s several folders, one of them called `Runfirstall`. I have the next code:

```
DIR="/media/Roy/Analysis"  

for group in Controls Patients; 
    do
    echo $group 
    for folder in $DIR/$group/!(Runfirstall)/
        do
        name=$(basename "$folder")  
        echo $name 
    done;
done;
```

Which gives me this error:

```
./test.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 7: `    for folder in $DIR/$group/!(Runfirstall)'
```

The thing is, if I execute extglob just before the script gives me:

```
shopt extglob 
extglob         on
```

Comment: Related and might be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328910/how-to-avoid-certain-directory-or-files-while-copying-from-main-directory

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script's shell options aren't inherited from the interactive shell in which it is run - you need an explicit

```
shopt -s extglob
```

*inside* the script.

You should also add a `#!/bin/bash` shebang to the top of the script to make it clear what shell should be used.